# sending parameter from unit testcase for reqparse.RequestParser in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask-restful

I am trying to write unit testcase of Restplus-Flask application.

```
@deployment.route('/abc/xyz')
class Depl(Resource):
    @deployment.expect(depl_arg, validate=True)
    @deployment.expect(depl_arguments, validate=True)
    @deployment.response(description='deployment',code=200)                                  
    @deployment.marshal_with(depl_model)
    def get(self, **kwargs):
        request_args = depl_arguments.parse_args(strict=True)
        name = request_args['name']
        print(name)
```

Here is my unit testcase:

```
def testfunc(self):
    parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
    parser.add_argument('name', type=str, required=False)
    res = Depl(args).get()
    self.assertIsNone(res)
```

But I am not able to find a proper way to send the req_arg to 'get' function.
can anybody help me out here how to pass name argument from a unit testcase.